Using a loop and df.query
I have a matrix (17,11).
For each point, I have a several values (go3), because I have 9 rows for each day.

I have to select each "longitude" (it is like axis X) and each "latitude" (its like axis Y), and put all this values on a dataframe, and after that, I have to groupby by day, to obtain the mean value, and export to a csv.
I know how to do one by one.
dl_1=d.query('longitude==-55 and latitude==-18.5')
daily_resampled_data_1 = dl_1.resample('D').mean()
daily_resampled_data_1.to_csv('CAMS_ponto1_O3.csv')
daily_resampled_data_1

But I don't know how use query in a for-loop.
I need help, to create this loop, to simplify my task.
I expect something like this:
    latitudes = [-18.5, -19.25, -20.0, -20.75, -21.5, -22.25, -23.0, -23.75, -24.5, -25.25,-26.0]
    longitudes = [-55.0, -54.25, -53.5, -52.75, -52.0, -51.25, -50.5, -49.75, -49.0, -48.25, 47.5, -46.75, -46.0, -45.25, -44.5, -43.75, -43.0]

for x in latitude:
       for y in longitude:
           dl_[x][y]=d.query('longitude==[x] and latitude==[y]')
           daily_resampled_data_[x][y] = dl_[x][y].resample('D').mean()
           daily_resampled_data_[x][y].to_csv('CAMS_ponto[x][y]_O3.csv')
           

Is this possible?
Update
I need this loop, to check every combination.
For example:
1º row: (-55, -18.5), (-55, -19.25), (-55, -20)...
2º row: (-54.25, -18.5), (-54.25, -19.25)...
And each of this points, I want to use something like this:
dl_[x][y]=d.query('longitude==[x] and latitude==[y]')
daily_resampled_data_[x][y] = dl_[x][y].resample('D').mean()
daily_resampled_data_[x][y].to_csv('CAMS_ponto[x][y]_O3.csv')

The out put, should be like this:



Why don't you use DataFrameGroupby.resample?

In the example you need to move the to_csv out of the loop

Please post your expected output sample

I'll post some expect outputs

I think you mainly want to understand how to use the query part on a loop. If this is right, please take a look at the below code.
df['lat_lon']=df['latitude'].astype(str)+df['longitude'].astype(str) 
df.index=df['datetime']
unique_lat_lon=df['lat_lon'].unique()
for unique_comb in unique_lat_lon:
    df_filt=df.loc[df['lat_lon']==unique_comb]
    df_filt = df_filt.resample('D').mean()
    df_filt.to_csv(rf"C:\Users\743622\Downloads\trial\cams_{unique_comb}.csv")
    


Consider DataFrameGroupBy.Resample to resample time series data to daily means across all non-missing pairings of latitude and longitude.
For single data frame:
daily_means = (
    d.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude'])
     .resample('D').mean()
)

For multiple CSVs:
for g, df in d.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']):
    (
        df.resample('D').mean()
          .to_csv(f'CAMS_ponto{g[0]}{g[1]}_O3.csv')
    )

